# _Context Select method or tostring() wont work with enum

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, list, enums, casting

I have the following Enum

```
public enum LicenseTypes
{
    Go = 1,
    GoPlus = 2,
}
```

And the following Class (which uses the emum):

```
public class Licenses
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string ResponsibleSeller { get; set; }
    public LicenseTypes LicenseType { get; set; }
}
```

When I try in my controller:

```
...
ApplicationDbContext _context    
return View(_context.Licenses.ToList());
```

I get an error "Specified cast is not valid."
I tried instead

```
IEnumerable<Licenses> DB1 = _context.Licenses.Select(x => new Licenses {LicenseType = x.LicenseType,....});
```

But get the same error.
How do I make a list of _context.Licenses where in fact, in the DB, the LicenseType is obviously stored as string???

Comment: Your class is called Licenses. I think your DbContext would then be Licensess(?) Please check. A better way would be to call the class a singular "License" and then the _context can be "Licenses."

Comment: Thats not the problem... 
I assume I need to cast string to Enum, but how do i combine that with the Select method?

Comment: What version of EF are you using? Support for enums in EF came from EF 5.0 and onwards.

Comment: "EntityFramework.Commands": "7.0.0-rc1-final"

Comment: Ok. does the "Licenses" method explicitly exist in your DbContext?